# Woking of next.js in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have been using the next.js for a while now. but I don't really understand how it works in production. My understanding is when we make a request to the server then the server gets the requested page from .next's static folder and runs the initialProps function of component and serves the response, so I wanted to know:

1. what happens when we click a link to another page (I've seen that the hit is made to the cdn but I am not sure what happens after that).
2. how does prefetching visible links works ( and if the prefetched component contains an initialProps function, does this function runs in browser?)
3. How does the next.js handles static and dynamic routes? is there any difference in their bundling to improve the load time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to double-check the NextJS document, **Routing** api. Your project with NextJS will be render on server at the first time (this behavior ensure 100% the SEO bot alway get full page html content), when user click on some link, that is client side rendering. You can test by console.log() in `getInitialProps` so you can test does client side run that method.